# "Cannot read property 'user_id' of undefined" with express-session on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, express-session

When I run my app locally my session works without any problem. But when I deploy it to Heroku my session stops working.

My app config is here:

```
const express = require('express');
const session = require('express-session');
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mysql = require('mysql');

// Setting up CORS, such that it can work together with an Application at another domain / port
index.use(cors({origin: [myapplink.com], credentials: true}));

// For being able to read request bodies
index.use(bodyParser.json());

// Initializing the session magic of express-session package
index.use(session({
    secret: "secret",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {
      expires: 7*24*3600*1000,
    }));
```

Here is the where I am using the session:

```
//LOGIN
index.post("/api/login", function (req, res) {
  loginQuery = `SELECT user_id, username, gold, powder, settings FROM users WHERE (email = '${req.body.username}' OR username = '${req.body.username}') AND password = '${req.body.password}'`;
  pool.query(loginQuery, function (error, rows) {
    if (error) {
      console.error(error);
    } else {
      if (rows.length===1) {
        req.session.userData = rows[0];
        return res.status(200).send(true)
      } else {
        return res.status(500).send({
          error: 'Bad login data'
        });
      }
    }
  })
});
```

And example of error is here:

```
/**
 * Gets all user cards
 */
index.get('/api/getUnlockedCards', (req, res) => {
  query = `SELECT DISTINCT unlockedCards.card_id, cards.* FROM unlockedCards INNER JOIN cards ON unlockedCards.card_id = cards.card_id where unlockedCards.user_id = '${req.session.userData.user_id}'`;
  pool.query(query, function (error, rows) {
    if (error) {
      console.error(error);
    } else {
      return res.status(200).send(rows)
    }
  })
});
```

The problem is that when I try to call this endpoint I get the following error:

```
2020-07-26T16:28:54.693750+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: Cannot read property 'user_id' of undefined
2020-07-26T16:28:54.693750+00:00 app[web.1]: at Query.<anonymous> (/app/index.js:354:38)
2020-07-26T16:28:54.693751+00:00 app[web.1]: at Query.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:526:10)
2020-07-26T16:28:54.693751+00:00 app[web.1]: at Query._callback (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:488:16)
2020-07-26T16:28:54.693752+00:00 app[web.1]: at Query.Sequence.end (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:83:24)
2020-07-26T16:28:54.693753+00:00 app[web.1]: at Query._handleFinalResultPacket (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:149:8)
2020-07-26T16:28:54.693753+00:00 app[web.1]: at Query.EofPacket (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:133:8)
2020-07-26T16:28:54.693754+00:00 app[web.1]: at Protocol._parsePacket (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:291:23)
2020-07-26T16:28:54.693754+00:00 app[web.1]: at Parser._parsePacket (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:433:10)
2020-07-26T16:28:54.693755+00:00 app[web.1]: at Parser.write (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:43:10)
2020-07-26T16:28:54.693755+00:00 app[web.1]: at Protocol.write (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:38:16)
```

What is the problem, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a session backend being selected here. [The default won't work well on Heroku](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session#api), where you probably have more than one active process:

> **Warning** The default server-side session storage, `MemoryStore`, is *purposely* not designed for a production environment. It will leak memory under most conditions, does not scale past a single process, and is meant for debugging and developing.

There are [*lots* of other back-ends](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session#compatible-session-stores). Pick one that's backed by some kind of shared persistence layer (maybe MySQL since you're already using that), install the session store backend, and [use it  as your `store` when you instantiate your session object](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session#store).

Answer (score 0):

add app.enable('trust proxy') before routes and other middlewares in your index.js file